# When does there exist a joint probability distribution described by a Fokker-Planck equation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

If all marginals of a joint probability distribution evolve according to a Fokker-Planck equation ([https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker–Planck_equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)), is it guaranteed that the joint probability distribution itself evolves according to a Fokker-Planck equation?

By “all marginals” I mean all marginal distributions integrated over not just the 2 primary axes of the 2D distribution, but also all linear combinations of those axes.

If so, is there a well known way to reconstruct the Fokker-Planck equation of the joint distribution from the marginals? In my case each marginal has slightly different drift and diffusion coefficients.

Thanks in advance for any help!